# Using multiple AND operators in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have multiple conditions that i want to check on database column can i do it like this?

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PscData where SETTLEMENT_ID = T.SETTLEMENT_ID AND NO_OF_BUFFALO >= 1
            AND NO_OF_COW >= 1
            AND NO_OF_GOAT >= 1
            AND NO_OF_SHEEP >= 1
            ) as At_Least_1_Buffalo_Bullock_Cow_Goat_Sheep
```

It is not giving me the accurate answer.
I want total count from my data where there is at-least 1 cow, goat, sheep or buffalo.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Y do you need SETTLEMENT_ID = T.SETTLEMENT_ID?? what is T here

Comment: Your query = Counting total records in PscData, if records has SETTLEMENT_ID  = T.SettleMent_ID. At the same time, NO_OF_BUFFALO  has more than 1 AND NO_OF_COW  has more than 1 AND NO_OF_GOAT has more than 1 AND NO_OF_SHEEP has more than 1. Do you need AND condition or OR condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `OR` instead of `AND` in the `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PscData where SETTLEMENT_ID  = T.SETTLEMENT_ID AND (
        NO_OF_BUFFALO >= 1
            OR NO_OF_COW >= 1
            OR NO_OF_GOAT >= 1
            OR NO_OF_SHEEP >= 1)
```

Comment: Personally, I think it would be cleaner to write `> 0` instead of `>= 1`...

Answer (score 0):

@Eralper has one way but logically I think this describes what you want better

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PscData where SETTLEMENT_ID = T.SETTLEMENT_ID AND  (NO_OF_BUFFALO >= 1
            OR NO_OF_COW >= 1
            OR NO_OF_GOAT >= 1
            OR NO_OF_SHEEP >= 1
            ) ) as At_Least_1_Buffalo_Bullock_Cow_Goat_Sheep
```

Note the use of `OR` rather than `AND` for the separate conditions.

Comment: i am using AND because i want all these conditions to be true nd then return the results.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is below query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM PscData 
where 
SETTLEMENT_ID = T.SETTLEMENT_ID AND 
( NO_OF_BUFFALO + NO_OF_COW + NO_OF_GOAT + NO_OF_SHEEP) >= 1
--SUM( NO_OF_BUFFALO + NO_OF_COW + NO_OF_GOAT + NO_OF_SHEEP) >= 1
```

Sorry for the typo, we don't need for the SUM() function here, I commented it out.

Comment: That's not valid sql (try using Having for the aggregate condition)

Comment: thanks for warning, we don't need the sum() here, I'm already summing the columns using "+" operator